# Why isn't the existence of all minimum-width integer types (up to 64 bits) required?

Tags: c, c99, stdint

In both C99 and C11 (at least their final drafts), we find that the existence of `uint_least8_t`, `uint_least16_t`, `uint_least32_t`, `uint_least64_t` in `<stdint.h>` is required, along with their signed variants.

I'd think that a requirement of the availability of `uint_least{N}_t` for all *N* between 1 and 64 would be reasonable. Is there a good reason why this isn't the case? If implementations must supply 8, 16, 32, and 64, then surely an implementation for all smaller values of *N* should be feasible (e.g. `typedef uint_least16_t uint_least15_t;` etc. would be obvious for x86).

I'm asking because I found myself wanting a `uint_least21_t` type to store a single Unicode codepoint, which can have any value between `U+0000` and `U+10FFFF` inclusive (a constraint introduced in Unicode 4.0). I'd think this would be a more accurate choice, in case some target architecture happens to have (for instance) fast 24-bit integers. Right now, I'm stuck with a big preprocessor section, where I'm testing `defined(UINT_LEAST{N}_MAX)` with *N* between 21 and 32 to pick the right type.

Answer (score 1):

Most modern hardware (and compilers) current since 1999 can reasonably implement 8,16,32, and 64 bit unsigned types.   In fact, on a fair few modern implementations, `unsigned char`, `unsigned short`, `unsigned long`, and `unsigned long long` ARE implemented as 8,16,32, and 64 bit unsigned types - although, strictly strictly speaking, that is permitted but not required.

That means, for compiler vendors, `uint_least8_t`, `uint_least16_t`, `uint_least32_t`,  `uint_least64_t` can be easily supported.   Compiler vendors would not put up strong resistance.

That is not the case for other such types.  For example, there are very few instances of hardware that natively supports an unsigned integral type of the form `uint_least`N`_t` for other values of N.   Which means the compiler (or library) would need to emulate those types  (probably in terms of native types that the hardware does support).

Furthermore, relatively few programmers, in practice, have a burning need for (say) a `uint_least21_t`, and even fewer are willing to lay down cold hard cash to buy a compiler and library that does.

So there is a combination of circumstances.   Compiler or library vendors (who have a vote in committee proceedings) would be less than enthused at emulating such types unless there is profit in it (i.e. a lot of paying customers offering to pay good money for a compiler or library with such features).    Furthermore, there would be relatively few programmers with the interest in using such a feature with enough commercial or political clout to convince a vendor it is worth the cost (man hours, etc) of developing their compilers and libraries to support such types.

The path of least resistance, for the standardisation committee, would be to only make a few of the types mandatory.   After all, there are more important features to vote into the standard than facilities which few programmers need, even fewer are willing to pay for, and that relatively few vendors would bother to implement.

Comment: "For example, there are very few instances of hardware that natively supports an unsigned integral type of the form `uint_least`N`_t` for other values of N." Are you thinking of `uint_`N`_t`? Because if not, I really don't understand what the problem is of defaulting to `typedef uint_least{M}_t uint_least{N}_t` for the first available M>N; as stated in my question. Such support can be guaranteed by simply generating a slide of these typedefs, between `#ifdef UINT_LEAST{N}_MAX`/`#endif`. IIUC, that's more of a chore than a technical hurdle.

Comment: Furthermore, your argument that "most modern [implementations][...] since 1999 can reasonably implement 8, 16, 32, and 64 bit unsigned types" falls flat when you notice that both C99 and C11 explicitly state that exact-width integer types (`uint8_t` etc.) are optional (section 7.20.1.1 clause 3 of the [C11 draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf), on page 290).

Comment: You think that compiler vendors are more likely to accept a chore (which increases their development cost, even if only a one-off) to provide a facility that few programmers will even use, let alone seek?   The committee process rarely seeks some technical nirvana.  For features to gain support for entry into the standard, they need to satisfy criteria of both technical (i.e. programmers will benefit) and non-technical (i.e. voting members will consider it worth the cost of implementing) considerations.

Comment: The same vendors are happy to implement language extensions with questionable benefits. I'd say that `uint_least21_t` is useful to communicate explicit and clear intent, while various GNU extensions encourage poor programming style (e.g. [case ranges](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Case-Ranges.html#Case-Ranges), [alternate keywords](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Alternate-Keywords.html#Alternate-Keywords), [unnamed fields](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Unnamed-Fields.html#Unnamed-Fields), and [`x?:y`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Conditionals.html#Conditionals))